# How can I check array value is already exist and add in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I just want to keep all **tags** in separate collection but dont add multiple same tag name so what is the syntax for checking if tags already exist

```
let tags = new Schema({
tags: Array
});



tags.create({ tags: req.body.tags})
```

req.body.tags = its sometimes single item array or multiple items array

Comment: Do you know about [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)? You can use that to make sure there is no duplicates. `array = Array.from(new Set(array))` removes all duplicates.

Comment: Are you using mongoose or another object modelling library?

Comment: In general this kind of operation, regardless of which database, is called "upsert". E.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/upsert-in-mongodb/

Comment: Please refine your question.   The answers below are going in the direction of given an `_id` for a `tag` schema, add new tag `foo` if it does not already exist in the array.  `$addtoSet` is the way to do that but your comment about "tags in a separate collection" introduces uncertainty.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want the MongoDB operator $addToSet - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/